# How to send PATCH request and change field to NULL?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, moshi

I am using Retrofit 2.9.0 to send network requests:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
  .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
  .build()
return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
```

and Moshi 2.4.0 for JSON serialization:

```
Moshi.Builder().build()
```

I have some model with a next field which can be null:

```
data class ChangeDutyEvent(
  @field:Json(name = "signature_date") var signatureDate: String? = null,
  ...
)
```

When I send PATCH request with some not null value of this field, it is working normaly - value updates on server. But when I send the same request with null value, its value on server is still not null. So, I think Retrofit or Moshi ignore null, how I can fix it?

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: @user987362 I end up sending an empty string. It's not the best solution, but it works in my case

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it works like that.

```
 val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi).withNullSerialization())
                        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                        .build()
```